# How to explain these differences in gcc vs nmake?

Tags: c, memory

I used gcc with Linux Ubuntu on a Dell workstation and Microsoft Visual C++ with a Lenovo workstation and got some following differences that I would like to explain.

A colleague even wrote an own malloc and I wonder which strategies there are for memory allocation. There seem to be different strategies to allocate locations in memory. There also seems to be a difference between (g)cc, nmake and others. For instance, (g)cc appears to ignore old allocation that was freed and rather allocates newly freed resources. This is how it looks with Microsoft Visual C++ :

```
Message MA01 from malloc.c: Hello, memory-allocating World!
MA02: Main array successfully allocated, with size 48 bytes.
MA03: Main array malloc returned address 988360 (dec), f14c8 (hex).
MA04: Main array now contains the following string:
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstu
g-count successfully allocated, with size 4 bytes.
g-count malloc returned address 988472 (dec), f1538 (hex).
Number of g's in array is 2.
Executed free( gcountp );
MA05: Cowabunga array successfully allocated, with size 11 bytes.
MA06: Cowabunga array malloc returned address 988472 (dec), f1538 (hex).
MA07: Cowabunga array now contains the following string: Cowabunga!
MA08: Main array now contains the following string:
Cowabunga!
g-count successfully allocated, with size 4 bytes.
g-count malloc returned address 988544 (dec), f1580 (hex).
Number of g's in array is 1.
Executed free( gcountp );
MA09: Executed free( arrayp );
g-count successfully allocated, with size 4 bytes.
g-count malloc returned address 988360 (dec), f14c8 (hex).
Number of g's in array is 1.
Executed free( gcountp );
MA10: Executed free( extrap );
```

With gcc on Ubuntu(Dell) it looks like this :

```
Message MA01 from malloc.c: Hello, memory-allocating World!
MA02: Main array successfully allocated, with size 48 bytes.
MA03: Main array malloc returned address 30273552 (dec), 1cdf010 (hex).
MA04: Main array now contains the following string:
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstu
g-count successfully allocated, with size 4 bytes.
g-count malloc returned address 30273616 (dec), 1cdf050 (hex).
Number of g's in array is 2.
Executed free( gcountp );
MA05: Cowabunga array successfully allocated, with size 11 bytes.
MA06: Cowabunga array malloc returned address 30273616 (dec), 1cdf050 (hex).
MA07: Cowabunga array now contains the following string: Cowabunga!
MA08: Main array now contains the following string:
Cowabunga!
g-count successfully allocated, with size 4 bytes.
g-count malloc returned address 30273648 (dec), 1cdf070 (hex).
Number of g's in array is 1.
Executed free( gcountp );
MA09: Executed free( arrayp );
g-count successfully allocated, with size 4 bytes.
g-count malloc returned address 30273648 (dec), 1cdf070 (hex).
Number of g's in array is 1.
Executed free( gcountp );
MA10: Executed free( extrap );
```

in short:

using MSVC++ :

```
alloc()  got addr1
alloc()  got addr2
alloc()  got addr3
free(ALL)
alloc()  got addr1
```

using gcc on Ubuntu :

```
alloc()  got addr1
alloc()  got addr2
alloc()  got addr3
free(ALL)
alloc()  got addr3
```

How does one explain these differences?...

Comment: Noone guarantees that this order would be the same tomorrow, on the same platform. What to explain here?.. malloc is allowed to return any address, including new one, as long as it is valid. Also, it's not about the compiler but rather libc implementation.

Comment: @keltar Perhaps the conclusion is that there is no one best strategy of which address is returned by malloc. I thought there could've been just one "best" strategy for the memory allocation and I'm searching for an explaination why there are many implementations of malloc and hwy people still choose today to write their own malloc when this project is so old.

Comment: Ouch... well, there isn't - libc's malloc is too generic. IIRC glibc uses dlmalloc algorithm, while OpenBSD's one uses mmap for every single allocation. Can't say about windows tho. But still - it would be really hard to implement generic allocator better than libc's one, but on specific cases it could win a lot.

Comment: `nmake` is the build tool not the compiler, please correct the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. That is interesting, but I'm not surprised. Your sample is very small though. You may want to loop some of those malloc/free commands to see if it's consistent. You're right that the m$ and *nix strategies for memory allocation and eventual garbage collection are different... why would you expect them to be the same. The language only defines what the compiler should interpret code as requiring, the compiler then must manage how to best arrange that behaviour for the target OS/machine type.

Answer (score 0):

The [concurrency CRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207192.aspx) in MSVC would provide similar pattern to the ptmalloc3 allocator in glibc which uses a [SLAB allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation) which by design provides optimized cache reuse with LIFO instead of the traditional FIFO allocator.